# What happens to fragments destroyed under ViewPager?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer

I have a ViewPager that has 7 pages, and I am retaining 4 of them while navigating and it gets destroyed after being replaced by another 4 set then GC.

```
 gPager.get().setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
```

Inside my custom `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`

```
@Override public Parcelable saveState() { return null; }
```

My problem is I am getting null pointer error even though I manually reinitialize the views in the Fragment after it is being destroyed like 'mDrawerLayout' and `mDrawerList`. Example:

```
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_layout_fragment, container, false);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) rootView.get().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) rootView.get().findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
```

If the other fragments are destroyed and some are being displayed on the screen in ViewPager's pages. Are these fragments recreated again or just being retained even it undergoes `onDestory`?

If `Frag2` is destroyed and `Frag1` is not. Does the viewPager(located in the Main Activity) will
call again the `setAdapter`? Or it will automatically skip the `setAdapter` and go directly to `MyCustomPagerAdapter` to populate the fragment destroyed?

@Override

```
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    SavePref saveState = new SavePref(mContext.get());

    switch(arg0){
        /** Android tab is selected */
        case 0:
            Frag f1 = new Frag1()
            return f1;

        case 1:
            Frag f2 = new Frag2()
            return f2;
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all `setOffscreenPageLimit(4)` means 4 on either side of the currently selected fragment will be kept in memory. So you may come to a point where 8 fragments are kept in memory excluding the one currently displayed. And secondly let `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` save the sate, don't override `saveState()`.

Comment: @M-WaJeEh I am using override the `saveState` because I am not and will not using `onConfig Changes`, thus I could retain the fragment state when there is `orientation change` which does not trigger null pointer. Does this affect the navigation even w/o orientation change?

Comment: I don't understand what you said. This method is for `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. Don't you want `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to save the state of your fragments?

Comment: If you are worried about orientation changes for the Fragment use the `setRetainInstance(true)` inside the Fragment's `onCreate` method to retain the Fragment even if the Activity is destroyed.This is recommended and even used when creating `AsyncTask` which must report to the new `Activity` after configuration changes.

Answer (score 0):

once view pager destroys fragments it will re crate using position and array , use the logic while  instantiateItem ..